# ttyUSB not recognized in ubuntu server

Tags: 14.04, server, serial-port

I have a very basic question here I believe. When installed ubuntu (Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS) and I type the command `dmesg | grep tty`, it gives me the following output:

```
renato@ubuntu:~$ dmesg | grep tty
[ 0.000000] console [tty0] enabled
[ 0.515141] 00:0b: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
[ 0.709774] tty tty2: hash matches
[ 5286.474897] usb 1-1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[ 5286.474959] usb 1-1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1
[ 5286.475016] usb 1-1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB2
```

As you can see my 3G modem is usually recognized. But if I install ubuntu server (the one with no graphical interface), the modem is not recognized.

Obviously there is some software that exists on the desktop version that does not exist in the version for servers, which prevents my modem to be recognized.

Can someone tell me what program I  can install on Ubuntu Server for it to recognize the ttyUSB?

Comment: If I install the server package ubuntu-desktop everything works, but then I'll spend memory needlessly

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The only way to solve this is to install the package

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

will consume a lot of RAM, but for this case it is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Please just install usb-modeswitch package.

```
sudo apt-get install usb-modeswitch
```

After that your modem device will be recognized as ttyUSB.

Answer (score 0):

I got my ttyUSBx devices (FTDI UARTs, SD card readers) working by installing the following on Ubuntu Server 16.04.1:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-extra-virtual
```